# MSDN quotes: Any Unhandled Exceptions are conveniently re-thrown onto the Host thread, even if you don't call Wait on the Task Object

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In the below Code, Unhandled Exception on the Go() method is not thrown back to the host thread. it is silently getting ignored.

```
static void Main()    // The Task class is in System.Threading.Tasks
{
    Task taskObj = Task.Factory.StartNew (Go);

    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("Executing on Main thread")
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Go()
{
    Console.WriteLine ("In the thread pool!");
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: Actually all the documentation I've found qoutes: "Any unhandled exceptions are conveniently rethrown onto the host thread when you call a tasks Wait method." This is also true when you try to get the result of a non-void Task

Comment: Where did you see this statement? Can you please share the link?

Comment: @OguzOzgul: Actually this statement is from C# in a nutshell ebook.

Comment: Please share the link, will you? You must have misread the statement

Comment: See [here](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=VENrFSQFco8C&pg=PA902&lpg=PA902&dq=C%23+in+a+nutshell+conveniently+rethrown&source=bl&ots=3wZ3ijeWbR&sig=ACfU3U1JYkusGD9AF_P0WRHrFFNcs4pJKg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdnNalzezoAhXSa8AKHVe7BA0Q6AEwAHoECAwQKA#v=onepage&q=C%23%20in%20a%20nutshell%20conveniently%20rethrown&f=false)

Comment: see [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Entering_the_Thread_Pool_via_TPL) : Any unhandled exceptions are conveniently rethrown onto the host thread when you call a task's Wait method. (If you don’t call Wait and instead abandon the task, an unhandled exception will shut down the process as with an ordinary thread.)

Comment: It says “abandon the task”, not leaving it alone

Comment: But how would you usually abandon the task?

Comment: By using a CancellationTokenSource

Comment: The title of this question is very long and contains part of the question. The title should identify the subject so that someone could decide if they are interested in the question, without reading the question. Also the body of the question should include all the information someone would need to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information copied by the book [C# 4.0 in a Nutshell: The Definitive Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596800959) by Joseph Albahari and Ben Albahari is outdated. The default exception behavior for [unobserved exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception) has been changed between .NET 4.0 and 4.5. Quoting from [Task Exception Handling in .NET 4.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/) by Stephen Toub, September 28th, 2011:

> To make it easier for developers to write asynchronous code based on Tasks, .NET 4.5 changes the default exception behavior for unobserved exceptions.  While unobserved exceptions will still cause the UnobservedTaskException event to be raised (not doing so would be a breaking change), the process will not crash by default.  Rather, the exception will end up getting eaten after the event is raised, regardless of whether an event handler observes the exception.  This behavior can be configured, though.  A new CLR configuration flag may be used to revert back to the crashing behavior of .NET 4.

Btw a [newer version](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491927062) of this book, covering C# 6 and .NET 4.6, has been published by the same authors.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the documentation, you need to call wait on task object for catching any exception in the task. With below correction of code, main thread will be able to catch the exception.

```
try
{
    Task taskObj = Task.Factory.StartNew(Go);

    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("Executing on Main thread");

    taskObj.Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}

static void Go()
{
    Console.WriteLine("In the thread pool!");
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: My last comment under the question has a link to a quote from C# in a Nutshell, and that says that the application shuts down even if I don't call Wait on the task object

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/tasks-and-unhandled-exceptions/

Comment: please check above. basically for unobserved task exceptions are handled on finalizer thread. In this case the program is exiting before this is happening.